# "exec: \"scripts/script.sh\": stat scripts/script.sh: no such file or directory

Tags: docker, go, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am getting this error while trying to bring up the first hyperledger network:

```
$ ./byfn.sh -m up
Starting with channel 'mychannel' and CLI timeout of '10' seconds and CLI delay of '3' seconds
Continue? [Y/n] y
proceeding ...
2018-05-13 07:33:04.240 UTC [main] main -> INFO 001 Exiting.....
LOCAL_VERSION=1.1.0
DOCKER_IMAGE_VERSION=1.1.0
Starting peer1.org1.example.com ... done
Starting peer1.org2.example.com ... done
Starting peer0.org1.example.com ... done
Starting peer0.org2.example.com ... done
Starting orderer.example.com    ... done
cli is up-to-date
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"scripts/script.sh\": stat scripts/script.sh: no such file or directory": unknown
ERROR !!!! Test failed
```

The main folder fabric-samples is under the folder C:\User\XXXXX. This is the same path for $HOME as well. I can see that the file script.sh is present under fabric-samples/first-network/scripts.

Any other setting that needs to be done to help execute this?

Go version:

```
go version go1.10.2 windows/amd64
```

Comment: The container can't find `/scripts/script.sh`. It could be a problem with your Windows settings or it could be a problem with the image that the container uses to run hyperledger.

Comment: can you please elaborate? is there a way to find what causes the issue? earlier resolutions regarding this issue mentioned to place the main folder in the same path as $HOME.

Comment: Which version of Windows are you using?  If Windows 10, are you using Docker for Windows?  This error typically indicates that the folder in which the fabric-samples is located is not shared with Docker

Comment: Yes Windows 10 and Docker for Windows. The fabric-samples is located in C:/Users/XXXXX folder. If I go to the Settings->Shared Drives for dockers, it shows the 'C' drive as shared.

Comment: I encounter the same error in Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) Ubuntu. Can it be because Windows is preventing running the _sh_ file in another directory? Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I have just encountered the above error and have processed the following as mount the drive by command:

```
sudo mkdir /c
sudo mount --bind /mnt/c /c

cd /c/<your path>/fabric-samples/first-network
./byfn.sh generate
./byfn.sh up
```

good luck!

Comment: "sudo" command for linux, but u r generating script file as it's for windows, which OS r u using?!

Comment: @Farkhod Abdukodirov
windows use linux subsystem

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem on Ubuntu 18. I stopped all of my running Docker images and removed the exited images. After doing this, I was able to successfully run the byfn.sh script without the scripts.sh no such file error.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the `fabric-samples` folder should be at location: `C:\Users\fabric-samples`.
Now, the `first-network` folder should be found at location: `C:\Users\fabric-samples\first-network`.
I assume you ran command : `./byfn.sh -m` generate from `first-network` directory. Then, ran `./byfn.sh -m up` command, and you got that error.

Ensure that the path is correct and accordingly change path in environment variable `$HOME`.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue. I had mounted C drive and created a workspace there. eg.

> sudo mkdir /c
>
> sudo mount — bind /mnt/c /c
>
> mkdir /c/myspace&& cd /c/myspace
>
> /c/myspace

I was executing the following command outside my workspace. You can copy or execute the command after cd into your workspace. Hope it helps.

`curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/v1.4.0/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash`

Answer (score 0):

Try following method also, stop the network, remove all previous values:

```
$./byfn.sh down
$docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
$docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
$docker volume prune
```

Restart your docker then re-run the network!

```
$cd ....fabric-samples/first-network
$./byfn.sh generate
$./byfn.sh up
```

Answer (score 0):

Check home directory using

```
echo ~
```

Make sure `fabric-samples` folder is present in your home directory

```
cd ~
cd fabric-samples/first-network/
./byfn.sh -m down
./byfn.sh -m up
```